# Xcode Continue Build After Errors returns multiple errors even when disabled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The Xcode "Continue Build After Errors" option in Preferences by default is disabled but when building a project the compiler returns two errors for a source code below. Due to the mentioned and disabled "Continue Build After Errors" option, I would expect only one error would be returned.

Why the Xcode "Continue Build After Errors" disabled option returns more than one error? Maybe this options is more about continuing building a frameworks even one of them doesn't compile? Maybe this option works only with Objective-C?

```
class Toto {
    
    var str: [NSMutableString]  = []
    
    func toto() {
        str.append(NSString(string: "dded"))
        str.append(NSString(string: "dded"))
    }
}
```

[image: two compiler errors]

Comment: Do you see errors in other files as well? Or just multiple in one file? If the latter, maybe (this is just a theory) the compiler works on one file at a time, and can only stop after the bad file is fully processed

Comment: @pietrorea I have created other class in another file and effectively, when the option is enabled then compiler continue to compile other files. If disabled then if one file has one or more errors, a compiler will stop compiling.

Comment: IMHO, the option enables to continue building after errors occurred in one building phase. If disable , Xcode will stop at the end of a build phase if there is at least one error. This enable to have the list of all compilation errors in all files.

Answer (score 0):

You’re asking “why”, and the reason is that the compiler designers decided to do it that way.

The command “stop compiling after errors” has a purpose. The purpose is not to show a single error only, but to let you fix some bugs as quickly as possible. Most important if the bug will be fixed by a header file. So most likely errors from one file will be reported , and then compilation will stop except for files that are already submitted to other cores.